# JQuery Mobile - Panel side by side on larger screens

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, menu

I am trying to make a slide-in-menu that exists in two levels.
When you click on an item in the first slidemenu, a second slidemenu is opened.
This second slidemenu stands next to the slidemenu on larger screens, on smaller screens it overlays everything.

```
 http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/panels/index.html
```

In the docs it says the following:

When using markup to control panels, you can only have a single panel open at once. Clicking a link to open a panel while one is already open will auto-close the first. This is done to keep the markup-only configuration simple.

That said, it's possible to open multiple panels at once programmatically:

```
 $( "#idofpanel" )
    .panel( "open" , optionsHash )
      .then( function( options ) {
        $( "#idofpanel2" ).panel( "open" , options );
     });
```

But they don't say what the options should be.

My current html is this:

```
<div data-role="panel" id="gridItemDetailPanel" data-position="left" data-swipe-close="false" data-dismissible="false" data-display="overlay">
        <a  data-role="button" id="testOpen2" >test</a>
</div>
<div data-role="panel" id="gridItemDetailPanel2" data-position="left" data-display="overlay">
TEST2
</div>
```

Onclick #testOpen2

```
$("#testOpen2").click(function(){
   $( "#gridItemDetailPanel2" ).panel( "open");
});
```

When I click on #testOpen2, the first slidemenu disappears and the second appears.
How can I do this?